# How to evaluate the total probability using conditional probabilities?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian

Suppose we have 2 events $C_1$ and $C_2$ so that $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_1'$ and $C_2'$ partition the probability space. Let the event I'm interested in be denoted by $X$. $C_1$ and $C_2$ and their complements are conditionally independent given $X$. The probability of $X$ is given by,
\begin{equation*}
P(X)=P(X|C_1,C_2)P(C_1,C_2)+P(X|C_1',C_2)P(C_1',C_2)+P(X|C_1,C_2')P(C_1',C_2)+P(X|C_1',C_2')P(C_1',C_2')
\end{equation*}
Using conditional independence, we evaluate this as follows,
\begin{equation*}
P(X) =P(C_1|X)P(C_2|X)P(X)+P(C_1'|X)P(C_2|X)P(X)+P(C_1|X)P(C_2'|X)P(X)+P(C_1'|X)P(C_2'|X)P(X)
\end{equation*}
But then I have $P(X)$ on both side of the equality in the second equation. Is there a difference between these two (are the ones on the RHS the prior probability and the $P(X)$ on the LHS the posterior)? Any clarification would be appreciated.

In my case $P(X)$ is unknown, and I'm trying to solve for it. Would I go about this by guessing values of $P(X)$ for those on the RHS and evaluate this for the value of $P(X)$ on the LHS?

Comment: What if you divide both sides by $P(X)?$

Comment: Then I get $1$ on the LHS.

Comment: Yes, but look at the right-hand side.

Comment: That is the sum of the probabilities of the possible outcomes.

Comment: Doesn't that answer you question?

Comment: Thanks but no. My question is, how do I solve for $P(X)$?

Comment: I was looking at the question in the next-to-last paragraph; I guess I stopped reading too soon.  I don't see how you can use the first equation unless you know the values of the terms in it.  Your calculation is essentially just explaining why it's true.